# eBook series (trilogy?) about an Imperial Navy officer that is part of an Emperor's elite guard that is betrayed

Tags: story-identification, books

eBook series (trilogy?) about an Imperial Navy officer that is part of an Emperor's elite guard that is betrayed and has to protect the Emperor's daughter and takes revenge against those that have overthrown and killed the Emperor. The daughter ends up being a love interest. First book was free online and the subsequent 2 cost very little. I just can't remember the name of the series or find it anywhere online. Came out in the 2000's I believe.

Answer (score 6):

I finally remembered it!  *[The Last Praetorian](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16137916-the-last-praetorian)* (*The Redemption Trilogy* #1)

> Commander Jonathan Radec is a man desperately trying to escape from the mistakes of his past.
>
> Now the owner of Vanguard Shipping, his primary concerns are trying to keep his ships flying and his crew alive. However, the shadowy Syndicate organisation has set their sights on the Commander and his business, having sent a beautiful assassin to kill him. To make matters worse, she’s become the target of his infatuation, much to the dismay of his ex-girlfriend. Recently elevated to President of the Confederation, she’s still very much in love with him and capable of making his life a living hell.
>
> Surrounded by a galaxy beginning to tear itself apart, with enemies on all sides, he’s now also unwillingly tasked with trying to save the Confederation – for which he has little regard. Jon has little going in his favour, except a crew consisting of the elite of the old Imperial Navy, all of whom would fight to the death for him, and a past that possibly makes him one of the most dangerous men alive.

Comment: Please provide details of how it matches to help other people who might be looking for this in the future. Also, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If it's a question you asked, you have to wait two days after asking to accept it.